¿Cómo se llama este constructor en Java?
He visto este ejemplo en Java.
class One{

    public One foo() { return this; }
}

Mis preguntas son:
¿Qué tipo de constructor tiene class One? debido a que tiene un método con el nombre de la misma clase y se llama foo y ¿cuál es la función de este método?

bienvenido, es común confundirse como te estás confundiendo, sobre todo cuando uno empieza, así que no te sientas mal, nos pasó a todos.
Lo que estás viendo, no es un método constructor, sino que es un método común, que devuelve el objeto de la clase, o sea desglosando el código, el public te indica la visibilidad del método, el One el tipo devuelto, foo es el nombre del método, luego de los corchetes, tienes el return this;, en el que this es una referencia al objeto actual.
Ahora bien, para que sirve ese método... para nada, ya que para invocarlo, debes hacerlo desde el propio objeto, algo como:
One uno = new One();
One dos = uno.foo();

Eso serviría para tener dos referencias para el mismo objeto, que se puede hacer con:
One uno = new One();
One dos = uno;

Y no necesitamos crear ningún método extra.
Espero haberte aclarado el tema, sino, pregunta con confianza.

Pues el constructor de esa clase no aparece explícitamente en ese trozo de código.
De acuerdo con la documentación oficial de Oracle sobre constructores

You don't have to provide any constructors for your class, but you
must be careful when doing this. The compiler automatically provides a
no-argument, default constructor for any class without constructors.
This default constructor will call the no-argument constructor of the
superclass. In this situation, the compiler will complain if the
superclass doesn't have a no-argument constructor so you must verify
that it does. If your class has no explicit superclass, then it has an
implicit superclass of Object, which does have a no-argument
constructor.

Lo cual traducido al español viene a ser

No tienes que incluir un constructor en tu clase obligatoriamente, pero tienes que tener cuidado con esto. El compilador automáticamente generará un constructor por defecto con cero argumentos para cualquier clase sin constructores explícitos. Este constructor por defecto llamará al contructor de cero argumentos de su superclase. En este caso, el compilador generará un error si la superclase no tiene un constructor de cero argumentos por tanto debes verificar que lo tiene. Si tu clase no tiene una superclase explícita, entonces tiene una superclase implícita que es Object, la cual sí tiene contructor con cero argumentos.

En resumen, el constructor que tiene tu clase es el constructor con cero argumentos generado por el compilador que llama al constructor de cero argumentos de la clase Object.
Algo así pero que se genera en tiempo de compilación
class One {

   One() {
      super();
   }

   public One foo() { 
      return this; 
   }
}

El método foo NO es un constructor porque

Constructor declarations look like method declarations—except that
they use the name of the class and have no return type

es decir que los constructores usan el mismo nombre de la clase y no devuelven nada.
foo es un nombre clásico para métodos que no hacen nada o que solo se usan para hacer tests. Suelen aparecer en los exámenes de certificación del lenguaje Java para confundir, como parece ser el caso.
